# Creating a hash from an array of strings and arrays

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
[
  "temp-1",
  [69.63076923076923, 5.397898451463096],
  "temp-2",
  [70.44, 0.9044335243676014],
  "hum-1",
  [45.199999999999996, 0.09999999999999788],
  "hum-2",
  [43.82, 1.0568822072492268]
]
```

I want to convert it to a hash with the string as keys and the arrays as the value:

```
{
  "temp-1" => [69.63076923076923, 5.397898451463096],
  "temp-2" => [70.44, 0.9044335243676014],
  ...
}
```

What is a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Hash[...]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), here is an example:

```
=> array = ["temp-1", [69.63076923076923, 5.397898451463096], "temp-2", [70.44, 
0.9044335243676014], "hum-1", [45.199999999999996, 
0.09999999999999788], "hum-2", [43.82, 1.0568822072492268]]
=> Hash[*array]
#> {"temp-1"=>[69.63076923076923, 5.397898451463096], "temp-2"=>[70.44, 0.9044335243676014], "hum-1"=>[45.199999999999996, 0.09999999999999788], "hum-2"=>[43.82, 1.0568822072492268]}
```

Comment: Ah, `to_h` requires proper nested pairs.

Comment: It's so clean. Damn I love ruby!

Comment: ...or `arr.each_slice(2).to_h`.